# Unable to install a package in python using VCS support

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I have created my own package for internal usage, that resides on GitLab, I have followed the doc and have successfully created the package. It has `dist` and `whl` folders/files as well. Still. it is throwing this error:
`<gitlab link> does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.`
However it has both the mentioned files in the error.

Comment: A lot more details are needed for anyone to be able to help. What command lead to this error message? What is the project directory structure?

Comment: The error coming as `from Request.requestWrapper import WrapperRequest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Request'`

Directory structure is: 

`Data Sources
   -- DataSource.py
   -- __init__.py`
`Request
  --WrapReq.py
`
where I am calling the functions of WrapReq.py in DataSource.

Comment: This comment is unreadable. You should edit your question to add the details.